# How to write a more efficient query instead of using a Not Equals argument

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

A little rusty, but I would like to return all the `Email` in the `Customers` table which are not found in the `MailingList` table, So I'm using this query, but its taking a bit longer than expected.  Is there any other type of logic I can use to make it go faster (Instead of ie `M.Email <> C.Email` ?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT C.Email FROM CUSTOMERS C
 INNER JOIN MailingList M ON M.Email <> C.Email
 GROUP BY C.Email
```

Comment: you shouldn't need both DISTINCT and GROUP BY.  You could try your <> in a WHERE clause instead of the join.  Another thing you could do is index both email fields, or convert them to numeric indexes with all the text indexes in a lookup table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.Email FROM CUSTOMERS C
LEFT OUTER JOIN MailingList M ON M.Email = C.Email
WHERE M.Email is null
```

I don't think the grouping is necessary for either query.

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery might also do the trick

```
SELECT C.Email FROM CUSTOMERS C 
WHERE C.Email NOT IN (
  SELECT M.Email FROM MAILINGLIST
  WHERE M.EMAIL = C.EMAIL
)
```

For performance, ensure that you have an index on the EMAIL field in the MAILINGLIST table.